# Concave function (a estimate)

Tags: calculus

Let $f$ be cancave and non negative, that is $f''(x)<0$ on $[0,1]$. For $0<\mu<1/2$, show that $f(x)\geq \mu f(y)$, for any $x\in [\mu,1-\mu]$, $y\in [0,1]$.

Clearly, the minimum of $f$ over $[\mu,1-\mu]$ is $m=\min \{f(\mu),f(1-\mu)\}$. Then how to control the maximum of $f$ over $[0,1]$ by $m/\mu$?

Comment: As written, this makes no sense; you have a mixture of $a$ and $y$?

Comment: @T.Bongers I have corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: This would imply that $f(1/2) \ge \frac 1 2 f(y)$ for all $y \in [0, 1]$, or alternatively that $f(y) \le 2 f(1/2)$. This might be an interesting starting point for your analysis, and it also shows that you're missing an assumption of positivity.

Comment: @T.Bongers How to prove then?